# pairwise distance fails on a sparse matrix with an uninformative error message

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from scipy.spatial import distance

X = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(docs)
X = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(X)
print (X.shape) #prints (100, 1760)
```

However when I try to calculate the pair-distance I get this error:

```
distance.pdist(X, metric='cosine')
```

> ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.

The shape indicates that X is a 2-dimensional array, what could be the issue ?

**=====Update July 6th 2017======**

This is a bug in scipy, sklearn has the correct implementation for sparse matrices.

I have proposed a code-change to the scipy repository here:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7566

**=====Update Feb 23rd 2018======**

If you got here, you probably encountered that issue as well.

It's been more than 8 months since a one-line fix I proposed was pushed to the scipy repository.

Please comment [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7566) or [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7565), to get some attention from the scipy maintainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdist` starts with:

```
def pdist(X, metric='euclidean', p=2, w=None, V=None, VI=None):
    ....
    X = np.asarray(X, order='c')

    # The C code doesn't do striding.
    X = _copy_array_if_base_present(X)

    s = X.shape
    if len(s) != 2:
        raise ValueError('A 2-dimensional array must be passed.')
```

But if I make a `scipy.sparse` matrix, and apply `asarray` I don't get a 2d array:

```
In [258]: from scipy import sparse
In [259]: M = sparse.random(100,100, format='csr')
In [260]: M
Out[260]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [263]: np.asarray(M)
Out[263]: 
array(<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
In [264]: _.shape
Out[264]: ()
```

`pdist` is not designed to accept a sparse matrix.  A sparse matrix is not a subclass of `ndarray`.  You have to make it dense first.

```
In [266]: np.asarray(M.toarray()).shape
Out[266]: (100, 100)
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html

Comment: It's a shame, because most metrics (e.g. `cosine_similarity`) can be calculated rather efficiently on sparse matrices

Comment: `sklearn` has a pairwise distance function that works with sparse.

Comment: I believe @hpaulj refers to [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances ) as in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960292/7127519